# probabilities, group of students age

Tags: probability

a group of 6 students assembled randomly, each students age can be from 18 up to 22. What is the probability that 3 of them are younger than 19.

Been stuck on this probability and this is my logic:

- students age can be 18, 19, 20, 21, 22.
- the age that is "accepted" is 18(because it's supposed to be younger than 19

so, the probability for a person to be accepted is 1/5, there are 6 people and we need at least 3 of them to be successful:

$P(S_6=3)=C^3_6*(\frac{{1}}{{5}})^3*(1-\frac{{1}}{{5}})^{6-3}$

so this is the formula i ended up with and i am interested if it's correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, if for "3 of them" you mean "exactly 3 of them". This is an example of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

If an event has probability $p$ of "success" and $1-p$ for failure, and you repeat it $n$ times,

$$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Cheers! :)

*Perhaps "challenge" question: Find* $P(X \geq 3)$ i.e. at least 3 of the students are 18 years old. or $\leq 3$ :)

Comment: i am actually very interested in how to do your "challenge" but no idea where to even start, could you by any chance give a hint or a link where i could read more about it?

Comment: Well, one way is to simply add up $P(x=3,4,5,6)$, since that's equivalent to $P(x \geq 3)$. Or you can simply look up a binomial distribution cumulative table... I do not believe there's a short formula for it. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function (Just the "Cumulative distribtuion function" section under the wikipedia page).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help

Comment: np, hf :)))))))